# Flask render_template shows error when used to send parameter for iframe

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask endpoint that does this

```
src = 'src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=' +       googleAPIkey + '&origin=' + location + '&destination=' + dest + '\"'
 return render_template('map.html',link = src)
```

This code works fine if my template is this:

```
 <iframe
   width="800"
   height="600"
   frameborder="0" style="border:0"
   src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyAZ5styOuSR9i0VuS7FXTyHU2dPWDXQcm0&origin=mirpur&    destination=gulshan"  allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
```

However, it shows 404 not found error when i replace the src field like this:

```
<iframe
  width="800"
  height="600"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  {{link}}  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I checked that the link parameter is being sent perfectly by as it prints correctly if i put {{link}} in my template. However, for some reason it is not working in when in the src field of the iframe. Anyone can tell why?

Comment: Flask's `render_template` sanitizes your input for HTML rendering, which probably changes your `"` to `&quot;`. Try to change your Python code to include just the URL, then change your template to `src="{{link}}"`.

Comment: @Jan-Gerd  thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 src = 'src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=' +       googleAPIkey + '&origin=' + location + '&destination=' + dest + '\"'
 return render_template('map.html',link = src)
```

To

```
 src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key={api_key}&origin={location}&destination={dest}".format(api_key=googleAPIkey, location=location, dest=dest)
 return render_template('map.html', link=src)
```

And Replace

```
<iframe
  width="800"
  height="600"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  {{link}}  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

By

```
<iframe
  width="800"
  height="600"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src={{link}}
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

This should work.